# Does DynamoDB BatchWrite improve throughput when using lambdas or only latency?

Tags: amazon-web-services, performance, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, throughput

My initial intuition was to use BatchWrite wherever possible but the more I get familiar with DynamoDB and lambda I am thinking that if DynamoDB throughput is your main bottleneck (likely the case here), it shouldn't make a difference.

If I have an application where I don't care about latency of the individual write operation, shouldn't lambdas just scale up until the maximum throughput of DynamoDB is reached regardless of whether it is BatchWrite or single PutItem/UpdateItem calls?

If for any other reason single writes are advantageous (e.g.error handling), why don't I use them then? I would expect to be no difference in overall throughput. Is there an error in this logic? I didn't test yet.

Answer (score 0):

With individual requests you just waste resources. But lambda scales incredibly well and you might not even see it.

Long story short, making a dynamoDB query requires some hidden computation. You have to prepare you request, authenticate it, and send it over network. Making this twice will waste CPU time and network bandwidth compared to making a single query with twice the payload (but only one header).

It will at some point cost more to fire individual requests, but it's very possible than the overhead cost won't be an issue for you. That will most likely depends on your actual usage.

Comment: Ok, thanks but specifically in terms of DynamoDB write capacity as a bottleneck you agree that it doesn't make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

#### PutItem

Your `PutItem` request first reaches the request router, which will then identify the three storage nodes that are responsible for your item (based on the partition key) and sends the new data to all three storage nodes. As soon as two of the three storage nodes acknowledge the write, it responds to you that it has written the item.

#### BatchPutItem

*This is an educated guess, it's not officially documented as far as I know, but it makes sense in my opinion.*

When you send a `BatchPutItem` request, this request reaches the request router as well and contains multiple different items to write. For each individual item, the router will identify the relevant storage nodes, write to them and wait for two of them to acknowledge the write. This is most likely parallelized in some way and not completely sequential. As soon as all items have been processed (successfully or unsuccessfully) you get a response and DynamoDB will tell you which items failed.

#### Comparison and trade-offs

When you have to write multiple items, using individual `PutItem` calls **may result in more network connections to DynamoDB being established** from your clients, which is expensive in terms of time. But: existing TCP connections are usually kept around for a while and will be re-used, so this impact may be limited. For `BatchWriteItem` there are fewer network requests, which should improve the network latency.

There is as @aherve correctly points out in their [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68802716/6485881) also some overhead in sending a request to DynamoDB on the part of your client. You need to encode the data, calculate a few checksums and sign the request with your credentials, that requires CPU time, so minimizing the amount of request can be beneficial for your client.

For each individual item that you write, DynamoDB will consume the required write capacity units per item no matter if you use `BatchPutItem` or multiple `PutItem` calls. There is **no difference in terms of consumed write capacity**.

There may be some optimizations DynamoDB can do internally when checking authentication, but I don't expect this will be much, because DynamoDB still needs to authenticate each individual write, because of the [IAM conditions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/specifying-conditions.html) that you can use.

In terms of error handling, individual `PutItem` calls are very straightforward: If the write fails, the call fails and you can fix your data and retry. `BatchPutItem` requires more complex error handling, because the call will succeed, even if the writes partially failed. You need to check the response for failed items and retry them on your own. This is added complexity, that you need to maintain.